# Asymptotics of product $(1-1/p)$ over all primes.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am looking to solve the following problem:

Show that there exists a positive real number $A>0$ such that
$$
\prod_{p \text{ prime}\\\;\;  p\leq x} \left( 1 − \frac{1}{p} \right) = \frac {A}{\log x} ( 1 + O( \frac{1}{\log x} ) ) \quad
 \text{ as }\space x\rightarrow \infty
$$

I have been trying to get this result using Mertens second theorem but I have not been successful any help?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the $\log$ it is $$\sum_{p\le x}\log(1-p^{-1})=B+O(x^{-1})+\sum_{p\le x}p^{-1}=B+O(x^{-1})+\log\log x+M+O(1/\log x)$$ where the last step is the [strong form of Mertens theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Mertens'_second_theorem_and_the_prime_number_theorem)

Exponentiating the RHS and using that $$\exp(O(1/\log x))=1+O(1/\log x)$$
 gives the result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is the first step Taylor aprox of log(1-z)? Could you evaluate on that?